# Beit Av v.s. Mishpechah

Tags: commentaries, joshua--book-of

In [Joshua 2:12-13](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.2.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)(Mechon Mamre translation) the Torah reads:

> 12 Now therefore, I pray you, swear unto me by the LORD, since I have
> dealt kindly with you, that ye also will deal kindly with my father's
> house (Beit Av)--and give me a true token-- 13 and save alive my father, and my
> mother, and my brethren, and my sisters, and all that they have, and
> deliver our lives from death.'

And [verse 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.2.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) reads:

> Behold, when we come into the land, thou shalt bind this line of
> scarlet thread in the window which thou didst let us down by; and thou
> shalt gather unto thee into the house thy father, and thy mother, and
> thy brethren, and all thy father's household (Beit Av).

[Joshua 6:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.6.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [25](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.6.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> 23 And the young men the spies went in, and brought out Rahab, and her father, and her mother, and her brethren, and all that she had, all her kindred (Mishpachah) also they brought out; and they set them without the camp of Israel.  25 But Rahab the harlot, and her father's household, and all that she had, did Joshua save alive.

From these verses it seems that Mishpachah is part of Beit Av, while from Joshua [7:14-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.7.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it seems that Mishpachah is part of a Shevet and a Beit Av is part of a Mishpachah:

> 14 In the morning therefore ye shall draw near by your tribes; and it shall be, that the tribe which the LORD taketh shall come near by families; and the family which the LORD shall take shall come near by households; and the household which the LORD shall take shall come near man by man. 15 And it shall be that he that is taken with the devoted thing shall be burnt with fire, he and all that he hath; because he hath transgressed the covenant of the LORD, and because he hath wrought a wanton deed in Israel.' 16 So Joshua rose up early in the morning, and brought Israel near by their tribes; and the tribe of Judah was taken. 17 And he brought near the family of Judah; and he took the family of the Zerahites. And he brought near the family of the Zerahites man by man; and Zabdi was taken. 18 And he brought near his household man by man; and Achan, the son of Carmi, the son of Zabdi, the son of Zerah, of the tribe of Judah, was taken.

**Can anyone explain me which makes part of what?**

Comment: In light of my answer, below, you may want to clarify something in what you're seeking. Rachav was not Jewish at the time of the request (cited in the first verse). I gather from your question that you are seeking a general explanation of the terms as it applies only to Jewish tribes. The usage by Rachav may mean something very different. Specify please which angle you seek.

Comment: You may be right, but may I point out to you that Rachav and the spies utter the same kind of words (Joshua 2), and only from a story telling point the word Mishpachah is added (Joshua 6). So I don't know if the usage by Rachav is really that different. But your right that in different cultures and languages and context words can have a different meaning.

Comment: Simple explanation is mishpacha can be used both broadly and narrowly. So sometimes it is immediate family, and sometimes it is a large extended family.

Answer (score 1):

You can glean a sense of the purpose and hence inherent meaning of the 3 terms that you mentioned, from the [Bemidbar 1:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=7) - I've linked to the Rash"I commentary page as I will focus on his and the accompanying *Siftei Cachamim* commentary.

G-d tells Moses to count all the people למשפחותם לבית אבותם. Both terms are used.

משפחה is what identifies your tribe. In other words, when we see, later (like in the more detailed listing in parshat *Pinchas* (See Bemidbar 26:5 - 50,) they list the tribes and then the families of each tribe. E.g. - Reuven has the Chanoch family, the Chetzron family, etc. So, the tribe consists of families.

Now, what happens, if the mother is from, say, the Peretz family who is one of the Yehuda families, and the father is from the Palu family from Re'uven? Which tribe do the children belong to? That's the purpose of לבית אבותם - the father's household. In other words, the children are identified by the father's family, in this case, the children are considered Paluites and, thus, they are from the tribe of Reueven.

So in short - the shevet includes multiple *mishpachot*. *Bet Av* is used to identify the *mishpacha*, and hence the *shevet* of the children that result from a marriage that has two different *shevatim*.

---

Perhaps a better sense of these different terms can be gleaned from the end of the book of Bemidbar. See [Bemidbar 36:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=464&hilite=). You see, here both terms - ראשי אבות - "heads of the fathers" and משפחת - "the family of".

The verse says that the heads of the fathers from the family of Machir son of Gil'ad son of Menashe from among the families of the sons of Yoseph.

The heads of the fathers that approached Moshe and Elazar and the heads of the tribes are discussing what happens to the portion of the land that was assigned to the daughters of Tzlafchad (Tzlafchad was Gilad's brother.)

Now, why specifically did the "Heads of the fathers" approach and ask this question? Because, as explained above, the identity of the tribe follows that of the father. Now, what they asked was, "Wait a second! You Moses said, previously that since Tzelafchad had no sons, nonetheless, the daughters inherit the land. Seems to be an exception to the "father's inheritance" rule. OK. But, if Tzlefchad's daughters marry someone from another tribe, and they have children, the land inheritance goes according to the *bet avot*, meaning the father. So that would mean that the daughters of Tzlefchad would lose their previous land inheritance. There seems to be a contradiction."

So, from this story, we can also learn the same hierarchy and usage of the terms, as I mentioned, above.

Comment: B"N, I will look a bit more carefully at the context of the first verse from Joshua that you cited. I don't think  what Rachav said is inconsistent with my explanation. However, it seems that she is requesting that only her father's side of the family should be saved and not her mother's. However, considering that at this point, Rachav was not Jewish, (Midrash says that she converted) there's most likely a different meaning of the term, here.

Comment: Could it be that Joshua 6:23 should read: And the young men the spies went in, and brought out Rahab, and her father, and her mother, and her brethren, and all that she had. All her kindred (Mishpachah) they brought out. In this way it's more consistent with what you wrote.

Comment: [Yehoshua 6:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15790#v=23) shows *כָּל מִשְׁפְּחוֹתֶיהָ* which is translated as *all her families* Note the plural there as it apparently means what we might call *extended family* nowadays.

Comment: Targum translates מִשְׁפְּחוֹתֶיהָ as *zarayataha* which, I think, means "children".

Comment: @sabbahillel would you say 'all her families' contain different beit avadim?, or is it that a beit av contains different mishpachot? Or do you agree with what DanF wrote in his answer.

Comment: @DanF I noticed Shemot 1:1 talks about 'houses'  which is logical because after this (verse 2) all the sons of  (the mishpachah of) Ya'akov are mentioned as single units to identify them as beit av of Reuven, Shimon, Levi etc..

Comment: @Dan F While Bamidbar is talking about taking a census of the whole Israelite community 1.by their mishpechot of their ancestral houses (beit av), listing the males head by head. And 2. from each tribe, shall there be a man, the head of the ancestral home be chosen. Looking at one example: From Reuven, Elitzur son of Shede'ur was chosen. 1. From the tribe of Reuven, from the ancestral home of Shede'ur, Elitzur was chosen. 2. From the Mishpachah of Reuven, from the beit Av of Shede'ur, Elitzur was chosen. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: @all From the smallest social unit to the biggest how would one list: mishpachah, beit av, shevet/mateh (are there more terms?)?

Comment: Is it something like this: The family is the most basic unit of the Tribe. The unit above the individual family is the beit av - the father's house. Many fathers' houses comprised the mishpacha - the extended family. These served as a mishmar or ma'amad - the Temple service divisions, which were comprised of thousands of men. The total of the extended families made up the Tribe, and the Tribes made up the Nation.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpfull I understand your curiosity, but, at least for me, the recent comments are creating some overload. I'll focus on the original question. Bet Av and Mishpacha are separate items. A mishpacha is a subunit of the tribe. Bet Av would be considered an identifying "label" rather than a unit. As explained in my answer, when 2 mishpachot (a subunit of a tribe) marry each other & each mishpacha is from a different tribe, the *bet av* is a label that is used to identify the tribe of the immediate children. (continued below).

Comment: Somewhat analogous - in U.S. the mother is from the Friefeld family and the father is from the Greenstein family. When a child is born, he is considered to be from the father's family, and his last name is Greenstein, not Friefeld. In terms of hierarchy, then, the smallest unit is a mishpacha. Muany mishapachot comprise a shevet. The bet av is not a subunit of this hierarchy.

Comment: @DanF would you know if משפחות could be understand as מ-שפח-ות  'from a joined multitude - of family/families' ? Or is this far-fetched

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your word break-up, here. You seem to be focusing on a root form, שפח, but I don't know its meaning.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpfull I added a 2nd example, above. Hopefully, that will help you understand the hierarchy a bit better.